# Background gradient won't expand with contents

Tags: css, background, gradient

I have a gradient background in my website, which basically divides it into two colors horizontally:

Here's the CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f57171 0px, #f57171 600px, #FFFFFF 600px, #FFFFFF 100%);
}
```

This works fine, but if the contents of my website increases and I have to scroll down, the white color of the background won't go all the way to the end of the website. It should go from 600px to 100%, but it just stops.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: change `height` to `min-height`, and apply the `min-height:100%;` to both `html` and `body`. also, using `600px` as an arbitrary point is rather sloppy, i would do `50%` or something.

Comment: added as a full answer so you can maybe give me a checkmark :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the html to `100%` height, which is just the screen height. Try setting both `html` and `body` to `min-height:100%;`.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqF6D/).

Also, `600px` is an arbitrary point, I would do `50%` or something.